# Write a function with default column name inputs in dplyr::mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to write a function to calculate a new column in a data frame.  I want the function to have default column names as inputs, and to be able to be called from within `dplyr::mutate()`.

Here's a simplified example, where I am using a column called `age` to calculated a rounded age.

```
library(dplyr)
# function to round age WITH DEFAULT vector/column to round
round_age <- function(age = age) {
  round(age)
}

# create dummy data
data = data.frame(age = c(50.1, 60.5))

# try to use default age column - ERROR
data %>%
  mutate(
    age_round = round_age()
  )
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to mathematical function.

# specify age column to round - NO ERROR
data %>%
  mutate(
    age_round = round_age(age = age)
  )
#>    age pat_age age_round
#> 1 50.1    50.1        50
#> 2 60.5    60.5        60
```

I want to be able to call the function from within `dplyr::mutate` without specifying the data frame. Any ideas? All tips greatly appreciated!

Thank you!
Daniel

Comment: `data$age`?! Maybe?!

Comment: Your problem involves standard evaluation. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html for some help. In the meantime, I'll look through some old code where I circumvented this issue. Someone else could also answer it in that time.

Comment: @hmhensen I think you're right.  I couldn't work out the bang-bang, `enquo()`, `rlang` syntax into something that works without including the data frame as an input into the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a function called `round_x()` that wraps around `mutate()` and has `age` as a default argument:

```
library(dplyr)

round_x <- function(.data, x = age) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  var_name <- paste0("round_", quo_name(x))
  mutate(.data, !!var_name := round(!!x))
}
```

If we call this function with no arguments:

```
data %>% round_x()
#   age round_age
#1 50.1        50
#2 60.5        60
```

We could pass other arguments if we wanted to:

```
data.frame(data, weight = c(180.5, 200.6)) %>% round_x(weight)
#   age weight round_weight
#1 50.1  180.5          180
#2 60.5  200.6          201
```

Comment: I always struggle with `quo`, `enquo` and quotation in general. Do you mind explaining what `quo_name`, `!!var_name` and `!!x` are doing? Thanks

Comment: `quo_name`  just returns a character string of the expression contained in the quosure (in `round_x()` it will always just be a string of whatever you pass to `x`, so it will default to `"age"`). `!!var_name` is unquoting `var_name`, which contains a string `"round_age"` and assigning it to the name of our new variable using the special `:=` operator.  `!!x` is unquoting `x`, which is a quosure we created with `x <- enquo(x)`, which contains an expression `~age` -- the unquoting tells us to look for the variable age in the context of the dataframe specified by the `.data` pronoun.

Comment: I would also recommend reading the programming with dplyr vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) for a better explanation, or the metapgramming chapters from the WIP version of Advanced R (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/meta.html) if you want a very in depth explanation. I am still trying to wrap my head around all of this as well.

Comment: Thanks @DiceboyT, the solution where the data frame is passed to the function works great.  I am, however, trying to get a solution working from within `mutate()`.  I am teaching my team R at the moment, and I am trying to keep all the syntax as similar as possible (that is, create new columns in your data frame by using `mutate()`).